# C++ Visual Studio 2015 intellisense cannot find function definition of static library, but program works

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Using Visual Studio 2015, I created a static library in a Win32 console application project (MyLibrary.h, MyLibrary.cpp) and implemented the function "add."
I created another project (Project 2, for reference) to use the library, and I imported the following files: MyLibrary.h and MyLibrary.lib. The main function in the new project, Project 2, will call function add. The program does work; however, the intellisense shows a green wiggly line under the function declaration in MyLibrary.h and the message shows that the function definition for "add" cannot be found.

MyLibrary.h

```
#ifndef MYLIBRARY_H
#define MYLIBRARY_H

int add(int num1, int num2); //this is where the green line shows

#endif
```

MyLibrary.cpp 
This will not be included in the Project.
MyLibrary.cpp will be included.

```
#include "MyLibrary.h"

int add(int num1, int num2)
{
    return (num1 + num2);
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "MyLibrary.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << add(2, 3) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't worry about it. Intellisense can be quirky. As long as your build succeeds without warnings you should be fine.

Comment: It is green.  Green is good, red is bad.  It is giving you an opportunity to automatically add the function body.  And tells you that commands like GoTo Definition isn't going to work.  You can easily resist the temptation.